Determiners (the, a, some) that come before possessives (book's title, government's decision) help determine that Possessive or the noun after it?

The government's decision
A person's job
The children's book
The book's title

let's say, in the first line, what does the determiner (The) point to? "government" or "decision"?

'The government' of the country you are in, or are talking about.

It makes absolutely no difference in any of your examples if we remove the adjectival possessive element (government's, person's, children's, book's). The choice of determiner (the, a, some,...) isn't affected by the adjective - all tat mtters is the relationship between the actual "head" noun (decision, job, book, title) and the rest of the utterance.

"height" is uncountable? What if there are two buildings whose heights are identical? Or three buildings, where all three heights might be the same. And whether it's some government's decision or some company's decision, it's still just some decision that was made.

But contrast these with a baker’s dozen, where baker’s can be seen as a modifier denoting a particular kind of dozen. Likewise, a children’s book is a book written for young readers. Thus the OP’s the children’s book is ambiguous: it could denote a book belonging to the children.

@FumbleFingers It does make a difference. See my answer.

It depends entirely on the specific context whether a government's decision is being contrasted with that government's preference, or with the decision of the people (as expressed by a referendum, perhaps). The words themselves don't have their syntactic interrelationships "baked in".

@FumbleFingers Again, see my answer where I show that the determiner sometimes determines the first noun, and sometimes the second, so removing the adjectival possessive element would sometimes change what the determiner is determining.

@gotube: I'm not quite sure what you're getting at, but I don't see Some child's book anywhere on this page (the alternative phrasing where determiner some attaches to the book rather than the children). And without even that being flagged up, I'm not convinced the "scope of determiner" has really been addressed here.

A determiner determines the noun phrase that follows it. This means we have to figure out the deeper structure of the words that follow it to see what the first noun phrase is.
While all four of your examples appear to have the same [ determiner + noun + "'s" + noun ] structure on the surface, they are not the same, so let's go deeper and parse the words after the determiner.
In "[government]'s decision", "[person]'s job", and "[book]'s title", the noun directly after the article is a complete noun phrase, and the determiner determines it.
We can demonstrate this by changing the determiner:

The government's decision
A government's decision
Some government's decision

The first phrase refers to a specific (definite) government, while the second and third refer to an indefinite government.
The structure looks something like this (I'm leaving out some unnecessary detail):

[[The government]'s decision]

In other cases, including "A [children's book]", the whole [ noun + "'s" + noun ] structure is a noun phrase, and the determiner determines the head of that noun phrase. In this example, the determiner "A" determines the second noun, "book". Again, we can demonstrate this by changing the determiner:

The children's book
A children's book
Some children's book

The first phrase refers to a specific book written for children, and the other two mean a non-specific book written for children, so the determiner determines "book", which is the head of "children's book". "Children" is necessarily indefinite here.
The structure looks something like this:

[The [children's book]]

Aside: There's another possible reading of "The/Some children's book", to mean book belonging to the/some children, but going into that would be an unnecessary distraction to my answer, which still comes down to, "It depends on how the words after it parse".
